# Scope's proto and $parent are different

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive that creates a new child scope (by `scope: true`). Now in its template there is ng-repeat that creates a new child scope by itself. The issue is that from within the ng-repeat scope I cannot get to the properties of the parent scope, even though the `$parent` property of this scope is set to the directive's scope (which is correct, because it is its parent).

As I examined the scopes, the prototype for the ng-repeat scope is referring the scope above the directive's one, so the prototypal inheritance doesn't work and that's why I can't get to the directive's scope properties.

How come that the scope inheritance is broken like that? Is it possible that ng-repeat scope `$parent` property is set correctly, but the prototype of it is not?

Around the ng-repeat directive, there is correct scope of the directive.

Comment: use isolate scope instead .. assigned values as a scope property according to your need .

Comment: Sorry, this is not answer to my question. I don't really won't to use isolate scope for specific reasons. The way I have it now should work as it was designed in angular, but it doesn't and I do not know why.